# How to compose sales table for collections of items that are sold separately?

Tags: excel

I want to compose sales table for purchased and sold items to see total profit. It's easy to do when items are purchased and sold individually or as a lot. But how to handle situation when one buys collection of items and sells them one by one. For example, I buy a collection (C) of a hammer and a screwdriver and sell tools separately. If I would enter data into simple table as in the image, I would get wrong profit result.

When there are only two items, I could divide their purchase price randomly, but when there are many items and not all of them are yet sold, I can't easily see if this collection already made profit or not.

I expect correct output of profit. In this case collection cost was 10 and selling price of all collection items was 13. Thus it should show profit of 3, not loss of -7. I was thinking of adding 2 new column, like IsCollection, CollectionID. Then derive a formula, which would use either simple subtraction or would check price of a whole collection and subtract it from the sum of items that belong to that collection. Deriving such formula is another question... But maybe there is an easier way of accomplishing the same

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, please explain what is your expected output. Also, what you've tried to solve your problem?

Comment: I expect correct output of profit. In this case collection cost was 10 and selling price of all collection items was 13. Thus it should show profit of 3, not loss of 7. I will try something once I get any hint how others solve such problem, I dont know where to begin, how to assign something to collections.

Comment: please don't answer in comment, but edit your question, that would help us to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a column COLLECTION to identify item who belong to a collection.
Then I used SUMIF to sum sell price for items which belong at the same collection.
Then I used IF in Profit column to use summed sell price or single sell price.
You need to define in some formula a range of cell (see below).

**Problem: you can't add profit values to obtain Total profit.**

I used opencalc (but it should be almost the same in Excel).

Content of

```
SUM_COLL (row2):
    =SUMIF($A$1:$A$22;"="&A2;$D$1:$D$22)
SUM_COLL (row3):
    =SUMIF($A$1:$A$22;"="&A3;$D$1:$D$22)
and so on.


 Profit (row2):
     =IF(A2<>"";E2-C2;D2-C2)
    Profit (row3):
     =IF(A3<>"";E3-C3;D3-C3)


+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| COLLECTION | Item name | Purch Price | Sell Price | SUM_COLL | Profit |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|            | A         | 1           | 1.5        | 0        | 0.5    |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|            | B         | 2           | 2.1        | 0        | 0.1    |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| C          | C1        | 10          | 7          | 27       | 17     |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| C          | C2        | 10          | 6          | 27       | 17     |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| D          | D1        | 7           | 15         | 23       | 16     |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|            | E         | 8           | 12         | 0        | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| C          | C3        | 10          | 14         | 27       | 17     |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
| D          | D2        | 7           | 8          | 23       | 16     |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|            |           |             |            | 0        | 0      |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|            |           |             |            | 0        | 0      |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|            |           |             |            | 0        | 0      |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|            |           |             |            | 0        | 0      |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
```

**Update:**
I added two more column to make Profit summable:

```
COUNT_COLL (row2):
    =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$22;"="&A2)
COUNT_COLL (row3):
    =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$22;"="&A3)
Profit_SUMMABLE (row2)
    =IF(A2<>"";(E2-C2)/G2;D2-C2)
Profit_SUMMABLE (row3)
    =IF(A3<>"";(E3-C3)/G3;D3-C3)


+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
| COLLECTION | Item name | Purch Price | Sell Price | SUM_COLL | Profit | COUNT_COLL | Profit_SUMMABLE |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|            | A         | 1           | 1.5        | 0        | 0.5    | 0          | 0.5             |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|            | B         | 2           | 2.1        | 0        | 0.1    | 0          | 0.1             |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
| C          | C1        | 10          | 7          | 27       | 17     | 3          | 5.6666666667    |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
| C          | C2        | 10          | 6          | 27       | 17     | 3          | 5.6666666667    |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
| D          | D1        | 7           | 15         | 23       | 16     | 2          | 8               |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|            | E         | 8           | 12         | 0        | 4      | 0          | 4               |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
| C          | C3        | 10          | 14         | 27       | 17     | 3          | 5.6666666667    |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
| D          | D2        | 7           | 8          | 23       | 16     | 2          | 8               |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|            |           |             |            | 0        | 0      | 0          | 0               |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|            |           |             |            | 0        | 0      | 0          | 0               |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|            |           |             |            | 0        | 0      | 0          | 0               |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
... 
...
| TOTAL      |           |             |            |          | 87.6   |            | 37.6            |
+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I dont think this would show correct total profit. I have achieved the same with Excel but now I am thinking of dividing collection item total profit by the number of items in the collection. In such case total profit will show correct number, though each item profit will change with the successful sell of other collection item.

Comment: @wilkas see my addendum

Comment: I'll probably go with this answer after I complete making formulas and testing it out

Comment: Of course, you can apply same method for Purch Price to make it summable.